# How can I pass data to a component without props in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

in the question I mean this. Imagine that I want to show a component Called "Form" and inside of "Form" there is a list of components called "checkboxex"

The normal way to do that is something like this:

```
const checkboxes = [1, 2, 3];
<Form checkBoxes={checkboxex} />
```

and then inside Form I just map that (Array.map)

I want to know is there is a way to do this:

```
const checkboxes = [1, 2, 3];

<Form>
   checkboxes.map(id =>
    <Checkbox key={id} id={id}/>
</Form>
```

Can anyone explain me if it is possible and what's the difference ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: You don't want to pass props? I don't understand the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a general manner, both of the two methods are the same. They render some JSX in the parent component (`Form` ), somehow.

In the first one, you are passing the data to the parent, then somehow you want to use this data in its children.

In the second one, you intend to map the data, then pass a child component to the parent with this data. So, actually, you are passing the parent a prop: `children`. Your question does not reflect your needs here. But, you are asking the difference. The difference may be the logic of how you will use and what will you do in this `Form` and with its children.

Think about this scenario. You have a `handleClick` method in the `Form` component and you want to pass this to your child components, each `Checkbox`. Here is the two versions.

**Without children prop**

```js
const checkboxes = [1, 2, 3];

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form checkboxes={checkboxes} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Form = props => {
  const handleClick = id => console.log("id is", id);
  return (
    <div>
      {props.checkboxes.map(id => (
        <Checkbox id={id} key={id} handleClick={handleClick} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const Checkbox = props => {
  const handleClick = () => props.handleClick(props.id);

  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick} style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
      This is Checkbox and id is <strong>{props.id}</strong>
      .Click me and look the console.
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**With children prop**

```js
const checkboxes = [1, 2, 3];

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form>
          {checkboxes.map(id => (
            <Checkbox id={id} key={id} />
          ))}
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Form = props => {
  const handleClick = id => console.log("id is", id);
  return (
    <div>
      {React.Children.map(props.children, child =>
        React.cloneElement(child, {
          handleClick
        })
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const Checkbox = props => {
  const handleClick = () => props.handleClick(props.id);
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: "10px" }} onClick={handleClick}>
      This is Checkbox and id is <strong>{props.id}</strong>
      .Click me and look the console.
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

You can see the struggle here :) So, it is up to you choosing one of them according to your needs. If you don't set up a logic as in the second example you can use the `children` prop. Actually, you can create reusable components with this logic. I just tried to show an edge case here.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend :)

Answer (score 2):

The pattern that you have mentioned is `children` prop pattern, where the nested `JSX` gets passed to the component as the children.

When you include `JS` as part of `JSX`, you will have to wrap them in `{}`

```
<Form>
  { checkboxes.map(id => <Checkbox key={id} id={id} />) }
</Form>
```

Your `Form` component `render` method would look something like this.

```
render() {
  <div>
    {this.props.children}
  </div>
}
```

If the children that you passed is a function, you would just invoke it in the `Form` component.

```
<Form>
  {() => {
    return checkboxes.map(id => <Checkbox key={id} id={id} />)
  }}
</Form>
```

You just invoke the children cause it is passed as a function.

```
render() {
      <div>
        {this.props.children()}
      </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything passed inside a component like that is automatically converted to the `children` prop. You can access them inside `Form` like this:

```
//...
render() {
  <div>
    {this.props.children}
  </div>
}
//...
```

Comment: I'll test this later, thanks buddy if it works. I'll put your answer as the correct :)

Comment: @Deivbid, the answer is correct but your question is wrong :) You are still passing prop to the component. `children` is a prop for your component. So, it is better to change your question's title according to your real needs.